# How to use dynamic string to filter data frame using Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

DataFrame

```
    PROJECT  CLUSTER_x  MARKET_x  CLUSTER_y  MARKET_y     Exist
0   P17      A          CHINA     C          CHINA        both
1   P18      P          INDIA     P          INDIA        both
2   P16      P          AMERICA   P          AMERICA      both
3   P19      P          INDIA     P          JAPAN        both
```

This below code works perfectly alright and gives output as index 0 and 3

```
df_mismatched = df_common[ (df_common['MARKET_x'] != df_common['MARKET_y']) | (df_common['CLUSTER_x'] != df_common['CLUSTER_y']) ]
```

How we can dynamlically build such filter criteria? something like below code, so that next time hardcoding won't be necessary

```
str_common = '(df_common["MARKET_x"] != df_common["MARKET_y"]) | (df_common["CLUSTER_x"] != df_common["CLUSTER_y"])'
df_mismatched = df_common[str_common]
```

Comment: Maybe something like query?, like `con = "(MARKET_x!=MARKET_y)|(CLUSTER_x!=CLUSTER_y)"` then `df.query(con)`.

Comment: @SandeepKadapa - working nice, create answer ;)

Comment: it worked..perfect. @SandeepKadapa Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the dynamic purpose, you can use [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) in python like:

```
con = "(MARKET_x!=MARKET_y)|(CLUSTER_x!=CLUSTER_y)"
print(df.query(con))

  PROJECT CLUSTER_x MARKET_x CLUSTER_y MARKET_y Exist
0     P17         A    CHINA         C    CHINA  both
3     P18         P    INDIA         P    JAPAN  both
```

Remember that if the columns names have spaces or special characters it fails to produce the right results.