# complex pandas sub setting; selecting rows that match criteria in many columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm selecting data from a pandas dataframe which is ~1.5M rows by 22 columns. Each column is a sample and each row is an observation about a mutation. 1.0 means the sample has a mutation, 0.0 means the sample does not have the specific mutation and 0.5 means there is no data on that sample for that mutation.

The samples are from one of 3 tissue types, lets call the tissues AE, BE and HE. The samples fit into the categories as follows:

```
AE=["X14AE","X15AE","X22AE","X23AE","AE21.35","AE36.45","AE46.55","AE61.80",]
BE=["X161724BE","BE1.2","BE1.8","BE2","BE9.13"]
HE=["X11HE","X18HE","HE17.24","HE2.4.5.6","HE8.15","HE8.9"]
```

I've made the following queries with pandas, they all work but seem very clunky:

```
-Get variants in AE and in HE but not in BE
-Get variants in AE and in BE but not in HE
-Get variants in BE and in HE but not in AE
```

Here is the code:

```
    """Get variants in AE and in HE but not in BE"""
AE_HE_notBE = df.loc[((df["X14AE"] == 1.0) | (df["X15AE"] == 1.0) | (df["X22AE"] == 1.0) | 
        (df["X23AE"] == 1.0) | (df["AE21.35"] == 1.0) | (df["AE36.45"] == 1.0) | (df["AE61.80"] == 1.0)) &
((df["X11HE"] == 1.0) | (df["X18HE"] == 1.0) |(df["HE17.24"] == 1.0) |(df["HE2.4.5.6"] == 1.0) |
(df["HE8.15"] == 1.0) | (df["HE8.9"] == 1.0)) & ((df["X161724BE"] != 1.0) & (df["BE1.2"] != 1.0) &
(df["BE1.8"] != 1.0) & (df["BE2"] != 1.0) & (df["BE9.13"] != 1.0)) & ((df["X161724BE"] != 0.5) | (df["BE1.2"] != 0.5) |
(df["BE1.8"] != 0.5) | (df["BE2"] != 0.5) | (df["BE9.13"] != 0.5))]


"""Get variants in AE and in BE but not in HE"""
AE_BE_notHE = df.loc[((df["X14AE"] == 1.0) | (df["X15AE"] == 1.0) | (df["X22AE"] == 1.0) | 
        (df["X23AE"] == 1.0) | (df["AE21.35"] == 1.0) | (df["AE36.45"] == 1.0) | (df["AE61.80"] == 1.0)) &
((df["X11HE"] != 1.0) & (df["X18HE"] != 1.0) &(df["HE17.24"] != 1.0) & (df["HE2.4.5.6"] != 1.0) &
(df["HE8.15"] != 1.0) & (df["HE8.9"] != 1.0)) & 
 ((df["X11HE"] != 0.5) | (df["X18HE"] != 0.5) |(df["HE17.24"] != 0.5) |(df["HE2.4.5.6"] != 0.5) |
(df["HE8.15"] != 0.5) | (df["HE8.9"] != 0.5)) & 
 ((df["X161724BE"] == 1.0) | (df["BE1.2"] == 1.0) |
(df["BE1.8"] == 1.0) | (df["BE2"] != 1.0) | (df["BE9.13"] == 1.0))]

"""Get variants in BE and in HE but not in AE"""
BE_HE_notAE = df.loc[((df["X161724BE"] == 1.0) | (df["BE1.2"] == 1.0) |
        (df["BE1.8"] == 1.0) | (df["BE2"] != 1.0) | (df["BE9.13"] == 1.0)) &
((df["X11HE"] == 1.0) | (df["X18HE"] == 1.0) |(df["HE17.24"] == 1.0) |(df["HE2.4.5.6"] == 1.0) |
(df["HE8.15"] == 1.0) | (df["HE8.9"] == 1.0)) &
 ((df["X14AE"] != 1.0) & (df["X15AE"] != 1.0) & (df["X22AE"] != 1.0) &
(df["X23AE"] != 1.0) & (df["AE21.35"] != 1.0) & (df["AE36.45"] != 1.0) & (df["AE61.80"] != 1.0)) &
 ((df["X14AE"] != 0.5) | (df["X15AE"] != 0.5) | (df["X22AE"] != 0.5) | 
(df["X23AE"] != 0.5) | (df["AE21.35"] != 0.5) | (df["AE36.45"] != 0.5) | (df["AE61.80"] != 0.5))]
```

This works fine but seems incredibly clunky and just not very elegant and if I need to change a few things (such as sample names) it is time consuming to re-write, can anyone help me with a simple way to re-write this query? I was wondering if there is a way where I could just pass in each list with a criteria? Something like:

```
AE_HE_notBE = df.loc[((df.[at least 1 sample from AE_list] == 1.0) & (df.[at least 1 sample from HE_list] == 1.0) & (df.[no sample from BE_list] == 1.0) & (df.[at least 1 sample from BE_list] == 0.0))]
```

I find I need to subset rows based on multiple columns where the columns can be grouped quite regularly so if anyone can make this kind of query more concise I would really appreciate it. Many thanks

#

EDIT: Minimal example as requested:

```
mutations=[[1,1,0,0,0.5,0],
[1,0,0,0,1,0],
[1,1,0,0.5,0,0],
[0,0.5,0,1,0,1],
[0,1,0,0,0,0],
[1,0,0,0,0,0],
[1,0,1,0,1,0],
[0,0,0,1,0.5,1],
[0,1,1,1,0,0],
[1,0.5,0,1,0,0]]

import string
import pandas as pd
m_list=[x for x in string.ascii_lowercase[:10]]

df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['AE1','AE2','BE1','BE2','HE1','HE2']) 
for m,n in zip(m_list, mutations):
    df.loc[m]=n

AE=['AE1','AE2']
BE=['BE1','BE2']
HE=['HE1','HE2']

"""Get variants in AE and in HE but not in BE"""
AE_HE_notBE = df.loc[((df["AE1"] == 1.0) | (df["AE2"] == 1.0)) & ((df["HE1"] == 1.0) | (df["HE2"] == 1.0)) & ((df["BE1"] != 1.0) & (df["BE2"] != 1.0)) & ((df["BE2"] != 0.5) | (df["BE2"] != 0.5))]

"""Get variants in AE and in BE but not in HE"""
AE_BE_notHE = df.loc[((df["AE1"] == 1.0) | (df["AE2"] == 1.0)) & ((df["BE1"] == 1.0) | (df["BE2"] == 1.0)) & ((df["HE1"] != 1.0) & (df["HE2"] != 1.0)) & ((df["HE2"] != 0.5) | (df["HE2"] != 0.5))]

"""Get variants in BE and in HE but not in AE"""
BE_HE_notAE = df.loc[((df["BE1"] == 1.0) | (df["BE2"] == 1.0)) & ((df["HE1"] == 1.0) | (df["HE2"] == 1.0)) & ((df["AE1"] != 1.0) & (df["AE2"] != 1.0)) & ((df["AE2"] != 0.5) | (df["AE2"] != 0.5))]
```

This shows an extremely simplified minimal example of the problem. Multiple criteria are being used to select subsets of the df, I would like to perform a type of subset across a whole group of columns and a different type of subset on another group of columns, however this gets very messy when you have more than say 10 columns. A more realistic example is shown in the 1st example, as has been pointed out this is almost unreadable - which is exactly my point - is there a neater way to write this kind of complex query/subset where multiple columns require the same selective operation to be performed on them? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I've provided a minimal example that can be copied and pasted into a python terminal. The code being almost non readable is exactly my point - I'm hopeful that someone else has come across this problem before and knows a more effective and readable way to write this kind of complex subset

Comment: Consider checking this [`link`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52775917/how-to-use-dynamic-string-to-filter-data-frame-using-python-pandas/52776150#52776150) and also [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) + [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) / [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html#pandas.DataFrame.all) + [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

Vectorised, you can subset your dataframe and use equality and `any` / `all` operations:

```
# Get variants in AE and in HE but not in BE

m1 = df[AE].eq(1.0).any(1)
m2 = df[HE].eq(1.0).any(1)
m3 = df[BE].eq(0).all(1)

df_filtered = df.loc[m1 & m2 & m3]
```

If, as you describe, all your values are `0`, `0.5` or `1.0`, saying selected values cannot be `1.0` or `0.5` is the same as requiring them to be `0`.

Comment: This is a really great and concise piece of code - exactly what I'm looking for! My only question is: given that the 0.5 values are not a problem, as long as 'not all' columns in a given group such as 'AE' are 0.5. How can I use your code to build a subset where for example: in AE at least one col=1, in HE at least 1 col=1 and in BE no col can =1, but 1 BE must =0, however many cols are 0.5 doesn't matter as long as the right allocation of 1 and 0 is fullfilled.

Comment: for the BE condition you can use something like `df[BE].ne(1).any(1) & df[BE].eq(0).any(1)`; `ne` stands for "not equal".

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks for your help!